# Помогите с настройкой подключения

Tags: администрирование

Проблема в следующем. Имеется небольшая локальная сеть. Раздается интернет через роутер D-Link DIR-300.Подключены к роутеру через кабели, то есть к каждой машине прокинут кабель. Привезли новый комп, на этом месте уже стояла машина, интернет по кабелю на нее раньше раздавался нормально, тот системник убрали, привезли новый. Воткнул кабель интернета - огонек на кабеле инета мигает, работает, сетевая карта работает нормально.

Вопрос - как настроить чтобы на этой новой машине тоже был интернет. Сейчас при воткнутом кабеле инета - желтый треугольник внизу на месте значка подключения, доступ по локальной сети, без доступа к интернету. Я так понимаю что надо прописать dns адреса, настройки... А что писать, куда - фиг пойму. Где взять эти адреса, куда именно их их вписывать? Вписывать куда я примерно понял, там в протокол интернета версии 4 TCP/IPv4 - свойства - а дальше что и куда писать?

Может кто то подскажет как настроить?

Вообще я так понял что надо в протоколе 4 TCP/IPv4 в свойствах надо прописать предпочитаемый и альтернативный сервера DNS. На другой машине - где интернет раздается с того же роутера по кабелю - посмотрел - там в свойствах - общие не прописаны ни IP адрес, ни маска подсети, ни шлюз - все это галочка стоит - автоматически. А вот DNS сервер - прописаны. Цифры сейчас не помню точно - предпочитаемый DNS сервер что то типа 68.117.256.28 - за точность последних цифр не ручаюсь. а альтернативный DNS сервер - там везде восьмерка прописана - 8.8.8.8

Это так на машине где работает интернет от того же роутера. А в новый комп который к этой сети я подключаю - что прописать?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте настройки аналогично тем, которые на машинах с работающим инетом: получение ip-адреса автоматически, а DNS пропишите врукопашную.

Comment: Именно так и делал. Получение  ip-адреса автоматически, DNS предпочитаемый и альтернативный списал с машины подключенной к этому же роутеру где инет работает. Комп видит локалку, но без доступа к интернету.

Comment: В настройках D-Link DIR-300 фильтрация по MAC-адресу не включена (закладка Advanced, пункт MAC Filter)?

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что на компе Win7?Тогда вот инструкция http://remontka.pro/unidentified-network-windows-7/

Comment: Да нет, не неопознанная сеть.

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите на дир300 в настройках dhcp клиенты, какое количество максимальных клиентов, увеличьте его, возможно достигнут лимит)